# Não remontar colunas no grid do bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-3, vue.js

Como fazer com que os boxes do grid sejam exibidos corretamente sem encavalamento. Considerando que a altura deles será variável, pois o conteúdo é dinâmico.

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  data: {
   title: 'Boxes dinamicos sem encavalamento',
   itens:[
     {
       title: "Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit", 
       description: "reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
      },
     {
       title: "doloremque laudantium", 
       description: "dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores"
      },
     {
       title: "maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis", 
       description: "doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis"
      },
     {
       title: "laborum et dolorum", 
       description: "placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus."
      },
     {
       title: "Nam libero tempore", 
       description: " Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus"
      },
     {
       title: "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia", 
       description: "voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur"
      },
     {
       title: "Et harum quidem rerum facilis", 
       description: "molestiae non recusandae illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
      },
     {
       title: "Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit", 
       description: "reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
      }      
  ]
  }
});
```

```css
a.box:hover{
 text-decoration:none
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div v-for="item in itens" class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail box">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/500x300" alt="" />
          <h4>{{item.title}}</h4>
          <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Consegui resolver a situação provisoriamente de uma forma que ao meu ver não é muito elegante mas resolveu por enquanto. Incluí div com clearfix  dinamicamente conforme o viewport. Veja no codepen https://codepen.io/planweb/pen/PGLOQr

Se alguém tiver uma alternativa mais prática e elegante eu agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Existem vários plugins que já fazem isso pra você com muita facilidade, matchHeight, equalHeight e por ai vai.

http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/